# How can we simplify $\omega^{\omega\times \omega}$?

Tags: ordinals

I am trying to understand the ordinal $\omega^{\omega\times \omega}$, can it be simplified?

I come across this ordinal number as the fixed point of the normal function $\alpha\mapsto \alpha^\omega$ according to the construction on https://alchetron.com/Fixed-point-lemma-for-normal-functions . But I had a hard time understanding why intuitively it holds.

Comment: The lemma you link does not apply to $\alpha\mapsto \alpha^\omega$, because the function is not strictly increasing and therefore not normal. For instance, $(\omega+1)^\omega=\omega^\omega$.

Comment: $\omega^{\omega\cdot\omega}=\omega^{\omega^2}$ can't be simplified. The function $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^\omega$ is not normal (it's not continuous), and its only fixed points are $0$ and $1$. I followed your link and didn't see the function $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^\omega$ there. If your $\alpha^\omega$ was a typo for $\omega^\alpha$, the least fixed point is $\epsilon_0=\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes, that is my mistake. Now it is clear.